# php/mysql getting date formats

Tags: php, date

i'm compiling a church register and the dates are in this format yyyy-mm-dd
 example. 1978-03-27 .I need to make it 27th March,1978. Any php script to help me out?
I tried MSEXcel but messes it up. thanks (anyway..i'm getting it from a database) so i would be glad if i have it been read from a database or a file of dates.

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: are you getting the dates from database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```
$input     = '1978-03-27';
$timestamp = strtotime($input);
$output    = date('dS F, Y', $timestamp);
```

Reference to `date` format: [php.net](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.date.php)

Comment: +1 `$output    = date('dS M, Y', $timestamp);`  "M" for short representation of Month

Comment: `M` stands for shorten month name.

Comment: thanks man. can you help with a solution which reads from a database or a file of dates?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$in  = '1978-03-27';
$out = date('jS F Y',strtotime($in));

var_dump($out);
```

[`date()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) formats your output, and [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) converts your input to a timestamp. Keep in mind this will only work for values from 1970-01-01. If you want to work with "older" dates, you have to parse the input manually and generate the output you require.

Comment: aha!! i realized this. anyway..can i have a solution that reads from a file of dates or database of dates?

Comment: Please provide more details to what you want.